# why Search between 2 dates not working when install application in some computers?

Tags: c#

I have C sharp program and I confused about this issue ,

In search query between 2 dates when I installed the system in some computers its working and others computers not working .

This is the code :

```cs
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = @" select distinct   departments.dept_name,
                    LAB_RESULTS.order_id , 
           lab_results.patient_no , 
           patient_name ,
           Patients.Age as 'Age',
           case gender when 2 then 'Male' when 3 then 'Female' end as Gender,
           customers.custid as 'Customer Id',
           customers.custname ,
           status_name,
           lab_results.deptid,
           string_agg(testname,',')  AS 'Test Name',
           string_agg(lab_results.testid,',')  AS 'Test Id'
          -- coalesce(groups.groupdesc,labtests.testname) AS 'Test Name'

         from LAB_RESULTS 
    inner join patients on lab_results.patient_no = patients.patient_no
    inner join labtests on lab_results.testid = labtests.testid
    inner join customers on lab_results.custid = customers.custid
    inner join Departments on lab_results.deptid = departments.dept_id
    inner join Lab_Sample_status on LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_STATUS = [Lab_Sample_status].status_id
    inner join lab_orders on lab_results.order_id = lab_orders.order_id
    --left join  groups on lab_results.GROUPID = groups.groupid
    where lab_results.sample_status in (4,5,6) ";

    string condition = "";
    string orderBy = "";
    string groupby = "";
    orderBy += "order by order_id desc ";
    groupby += "group by departments.dept_name, LAB_RESULTS.order_id , lab_results.patient_no , patient_name ,[Age],Gender,customers.custid , customers.custname ,    status_name,  lab_orders.order_date,lab_results.deptid ";

    DateTime fromDate;
    DateTime toDate;

    if (!DateTime.TryParse(dtFromDate.Value.ToString(), out fromDate))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid From Date");
    }
    else if (!DateTime.TryParse(dtToDate.Value.ToString(), out toDate))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid to Date");
    }
    else
    {
        condition += " and cast(lab_orders.order_date as date) between '" + fromDate + "' and '" + toDate + "'";
    }
        
    DataTable dt = data.fireDatatable(string.Format(sql + condition+groupby+ orderBy));
    dgvResult.DataSource = dt;
    dgvResult.Refresh();
}
```

What is the issue and how to find the error and solve it actually some computers using English cultures and some using Arabic cultures so how to change the code to use always the correct date and run the query ?

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: Where is the variable dtFromDate coming from? Is it possible to define the culture in the sql query?

Comment: @JannickBreunis I have 2 datetimepiccker fields

Comment: Try dates like from 2 February to 3 March. If that works on all machines but 13 February does not then you know it is something to do with regional formatting i.e. dd/mm vs mm/dd

Comment: @bwakabats ok I will try

Comment: First you should use parameters to avoid the fact that the format of the dates can be different.  Second you should be converting to UTC and saving UTC in your DB so that running the code in different time zones will not result in different results.

Comment: Hi everyone of course there are better and more secure ways to do the above task but I think first we should find what could be problem with current solution.

Comment: @SandeepKGoyal you would be surprised how many issues have been resolved with just using parameters...

Comment: @juharr can you please give example how to do that , I changed the date format from control panel  ---> date settings for the PC's from dd/mm/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy  then its working but this is temporary solution what is the permenant solution and how to use parameters can you give example , thank you

Comment: What is `data` and what is `fireDatatable`?  Form the looks of it you'd need to update the code in there.  Here's an example of how to use parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#examples

Comment: @juharr if you mean by parameters use stored procedures I am using stored procedures for 90% in the system only some SELECT use this way but more than 90% of the system using stored procedures and parameters , thank you , data and firedatatable the database access layer and connect to the database from this file just call it in the place and windows need to contact inser , update , delete or select from the database .

Comment: No I don't mean stored procedures.  I mean your sql should be similar to `... where Date  == @SomeDate...` and then you'd do `command.Parameters.Add("@SomeDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = someDate;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your condition as

```
condition += " and cast(lab_orders.order_date as date) between CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + fromDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "',103) and CONVERT(DATETIME,''" + toDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "',103)";
```

Comment: It would be much better to use SQL Parameters.

Comment: absolutely @juharr but I was just trying to figure out what could be problem with current solution.

Comment: I will try this solution ,  I changed the date format from control panel ---> date settings for the PC's which not working from dd/mm/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy then its working but this is temporary solution what is the permenant solution and how to use parameters can you give example if this the best way ? thank you